# Countable subset of a Hilbert space generates a separable Hilbert subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

If $G$ is an arbitrary countable subset of a Hilbert space $H$ (over complex numbers), does $G$ somehow generate a separable Hilbert subspace? Preferably having $G$ as a countable dense subset? If so, what exactly is the procedure? If the claim is not true, what would be the counterexample?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of the span of $G$ would be a separable Hilbert space. It is unlikely that $G$ is in fact a countable dense subset of this space, however. For a simple counterexample, consider the sequence space $\ell_2$. This is generated by the standard basis vectors (which is a countable set), but these are clearly not dense in $\ell_2$. However, the set of linear combinations of elements of $G$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a countable dense subset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To make sure that I understand: my separable Hilbert subspace would be the closure of the set consisting of the elements of the form $$c_1g_1+...+c_ng_n,$$ where $c_i$'s are complex numbers and $g_i \in G$ for all $i.$ Also, my dense subset would consist of the elements of the form $$q_1g_1+...+q_ng_n,$$ where each $q_i$ is of the form $a+bi$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes - this is correct. I will change completion to closure in my answer (since the completion of a subset of a complete metric space is simply closure).

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!